# jQuery / Dojo - How do I use jQuery with Dojo toolkit

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

How do I use jQuery with Dojo toolkit? I've heard of both libraries being used simultaneously, jQuery for DOM-related and Dojo for UI (dijit), but I can't find any tutorials or examples of this.  Will I run into any conflicts or issues if I load both libraries?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use them beside each other with no issues because Dojo does not override $ like some other javascript libraries.

Answer (score 34):

You can use jQuery by pulling it into your app via a script tag in the head of your website, there will be no conflicts with dojo.

However something to keep in mind when using jQuery with dojo, especially with [dojo version 1.8](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/index.html) and its full AMD support. It is cleaner (**especially if you can't pull in jQuery in the head of your website**) to take advantage of AMD ([asynchronous module definition](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD)). You will need to make a package entry within the dojo config script to correctly pull in the framework. Here is an example that uses a library location for jquery and jquery-ui...

```
<!-- external library configuration code included in header to make sure this
    is loaded before code in body-->
    <!-- dojo config -->
    <script>
            /* Instead of using the inline dojo-config attribute
            * create this variable so we can configure dojo here.
            * This seems a little clearer, easier to read as a config.
            */
            var dojoConfig = {
                baseUrl: "./",
                async: true,
                isDebug: true,
                parseOnLoad: false,//false to allow for us to call this independantly in js later on

                //here are the packages dojo will be aware of and related js files
                packages: [
                    //dojo specific packages
                    {name: "dojo", location: "libs/dojo"},
                    {name: "dijit", location: "libs/dijit"},
                    {name: "dojox", location: "libs/dojox"},
                    {name: "jquery", location: "libs/jquery", main: "jquery-1.8.2"},
                    {name: "jqueryui", location: "libs/jquery", main: "jquery-ui-1.9.1"},
                ]

            };


    </script>
```

My folder structure just has a libs folder at the root, which is why I have "./" for the base url, but you could just as easily [pull from a cdn location](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/dojo_config/).

Without this config entry jQuery will not function as expected, and you may end up getting "*is not a function*" errors popping up in the console.

If you do put a separate script tag in to pull in jQuery or other third party framework and also use AMD to do the same, you'll just end up pulling it in a second time when you *[require](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/require.html)* it for dojo for the first time.

Answer (score 6):

**You can use Dojo's AMD loader to load jQuery.**

The following snippet even aliases `$` to `dojo.query` and still uses jQuery without conflict (I don't recommend it, though!):

```
  define.amd.jQuery = true;

  require(["jquery", "dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"],
  function(jquery, $) {
    $("output").style("visibility", "visible");     // using Dojo
    jquery("#output").css("visibility", "hidden");  // using jQuery
  });
```

Full explanation and source code: [Loading jQuery with Dojo 1.7 AMD loader](https://web.archive.org/web/20120326051918/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/loading_jquery_with_dojo_1_7_amd_loader2?lang=en)

Comment: Why do you not recommend it?

Comment: @JabberwockyDecompiler: It is not a good idea to alias `$` to `dojo.query` because it will be highly confusing for both jQuery and Dojo developers. It does not fit either group's coding conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You can namespace jQuery, for example, in order to avoid conflicts.

check http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

jQuery supports AMD for quite a while now.

You can use the "paths" property of your ADM config to tell your AMD loader where to find jQuery :

```
var amdconfig = {
  baseUrl: __AMD_CONFIG_BASE_URL__,
  packages: [
    {name: "dojo", location: "./lib/dojo"},
    {name: "app", location: "./app"}
  ],
  paths: {
    jquery: "./lib/jquery/jquery-1.12.4"
  }
};
```

Then, you can import jQuery into your ADM modules the same way you import any other AMD module, and use it alongside your Dojo modules:

```
define([
  "dojo/dom",
  "jquery"
], function(
  dom,
  $
) {
  
  ...

});
```

---

#### Note

You can use the same config for AMD projects that use RequireJS instead of Dojo :

```
if (require.config) {
  // RequireJS
  require.config(amdconfig);
} else {
  // Dojo
  require(amdconfig);
}
```