# IBM forms designer and making jQuery work with Dojo

Tags: jquery, dojo, lotus, ibm-connections

I have the following code:

```
var dojoConfig = {
   baseUrl: "./",
   async: true,
   isDebug: true,
   parseOnLoad: false,
   packages: [
     {name: "jQuery", location: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js", main: "jQuery"},
   ]
};
```

The code loads without issues but once i do this on a click button:

```
$(this).value();
```

It gives the error:

> There was an error executing the onClick event code on item , page
>   Welcome, form Form 1.
>        Caused by: Error: Illegal reference to $

What all do I need to do in order to get both working on the forms? Is there a certain way i need to call the jquery?

Comment: what does your console.log look like?  you may need to persist it

Comment: the console says **"There was an error executing the <b>onClick</b> event code on item <b></b>, page <b>Welcome</b>, form <b>Form 1</b>.<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Caused by: Error: Illegal reference to $"**

Comment: running into `$` conflict use: [jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: @charlietfl But where would i put that in the code above? I dont have access to the raw html code in IBM Forms Designer.

Comment: I would look at the browser's console to check to see if you have any cross domain issues there.  two links you might look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/loading_jquery_with_dojo_1_7_amd_loader2?lang=en and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850314/jquery-dojo-how-do-i-use-jquery-with-dojo-toolkit

Comment: might be better of just loading jQuery yourself at beggining of your code...  `if(!window.jQuery){ /* append jQ script tag*/}` then call no conflict right away

Comment: Tried all the above and still get that error.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Dojo config with this:

```
var dojoConfig = {
  async: true,
  isDebug: true,
  parseOnLoad: false,
  packages: [{
    name: "jQuery",
    location: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0",
    main: "jquery.min"
  }]
};
```

What happens if we do that is defining a module called jQuery (due to the `name` property) located at `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0`.

if we then use:

```
require([ "jQuery" ], function() {

});
```

It will load the main file of the jQuery module, which is in this case `jquery.min`. It will look for it at the given location, so you will get:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js
```

That should work properly, though I don't think the `.value()` function is a proper function. Well, you can see it work at this Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IE9y3cId6IHQfMKnyOtj?p=preview