# Using multiple selectors using document query

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo

I have a HTML tag

```
<div class="selected focused leafNode" data-test-id="4048800800000000::1" id="treeNode_5B9843E1"></div>
```

I am trying to get the div with a given data-test-id that has a '.selected' class.

I used the following query, but it doesn't seem to work

```
dojo.query('div.selected[data-test-id="404880f800000000::1"]')
```

Can anyone tell me how to call this right?

Comment: I'm going to assume its a actually a typo:  Your div has 4048800800000000 but your query is looking for 404880**f**800000000. Notice the f is in the query but not your div

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use hasClass method for checking the class and then get data-testing-id attribute data-test-id

```
$(function() {
      if($("div").hasClass("selected")) {
       let val =  $("div").attr("data-test-id");
         console.log(val) // 4048800800000000::1   
      }
      
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using the query command? I am evaluating the query on the backend using CSS selectors and am unable to use Jquery

Comment: This is using jQuery but OP's question is for the DOJO framework

Comment: you can follow this link for using jquery and dojo both. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850314/jquery-dojo-how-do-i-use-jquery-with-dojo-toolkit